# GWT Highcharts : Displaying 'Date' values on X-Axis

Tags: gwt, highcharts

I am using GWT Highcharts to draw a bar-graph.
The values for both X and Y axis are coming from the MySQL database.

The chart will display a graph having `vc` values on Y-Axis and corresponding `sampleno` (i.e. Date) on X-Axis.

Following is the code of loop that fills the series.

```
for(int i = 0; i < stats.size(); i++)
{        
     long sample = Long.parseLong(stats.get(i).getSampleno() + "");
     long n = (sample*60000);
     pointDate = new Date(n); 

     Point point = new Point( /* pointDate?? */ ,stats.get(i).getVc());         
     serPt.addPoint(point);                            
 }
```

The `sampleno` is some timestamp which I am converting into Date.

Now, Could you guide me how can I display this date as values on x-axis.

An [example on Moxie Group site](http://www.moxiegroup.com/moxieapps/gwt-highcharts/showcase/#featured-zoomable) does this, but the dates are in a fixed range there.

Please comment if any further explanation is needed.

Answer (score 1):

I advice to use labels formatter http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.labels.formatter and then return value by using http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Highcharts.dateFormat()

```
labels: {
            formatter: function() {

                return Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y/%m/%d',this.value);

            }
        }
```